# Programmatically getting the digital signature's digest algorithm for msi files in C++

Tags: winapi, windows-installer, digital-signature

I want to get the actual signature's algorithm (not the certificate's digest algorithm)­ that was used for signing a Windows installer file (msi).

Using Microsoft's crypt API, I was able to get what I want for exe's easily.
By 1st getting the HCRYPTMSG, then getting the signer information size, then the signer information PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO and finally by getting the algorithm itself :

> pSignerInfo->HashAlgorithm.pszObjId

```
BOOL bIsOk;
DWORD dwEncoding=0, dwContentType = 0, dwFormatType = 0, dwSignerInfo = 0;
std::string szFileName= "pathtothefile";

//Get message handle and store handle from the signed file.
HCERTSTORE hStore = NULL;
HCRYPTMSG hMsg = NULL;
bIsOk = CryptQueryObject(CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE, szFileName.c_str(), CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_ALL, CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ALL,
    0, &dwEncoding, &dwContentType, &dwFormatType, &hStore, &hMsg, NULL);
```

For some reason running my code on msi installer files always returns

> CRYPT_E_NO_MATCH 0x80092009 Cannot find the requested object.

Of course I have verified the paths and all the possible flags to the CryptQueryObject function but I feel the error might be misleading.

I'm wondering if the crypt API isn't compatible with msi files to begin with.

All topics out there seem to relate to the certificate's digest algorithm only.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problem is in the documentation for [CryptQueryObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptqueryobject):

> `CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE`: This parameter is a pointer to a null-terminated **Unicode** string that contains the path and name of the file to query.

Unicode in Windows documentation means UTF-16LE. However, you are passing a `std::string` (using `char` as the code unit representation). A `std::string` (on Windows) is encoded using either ASCII or ANSI (codepage encoding). You're going to have to change that to a `std::wstring` instead, which uses `wchar_t` as its code unit representation:

```
std::wstring szFileName= L"pathtothefile";
```

`wchar_t` unambiguously means UTF-16LE on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Unicode***: You need to use a Unicode string for the call (file name).

---

***CString***: As a quick test I used a standard **`CString`** in Visual Studio 2017 (Unicode). Please check. Just to get it to run for further debugging. Maybe you can include **`<atlstr.h>`** if you don't include **`CString`** already.

```
//#include "atlstr.h"
BOOL bIsOk; DWORD dwEncoding = 0, dwContentType = 0, dwFormatType = 0, dwSignerInfo = 0;
CString test = "C:\\LibreOffice_6.2.3_Win_x64.msi";

<..>

bIsOk = CryptQueryObject(CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE, test, CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_ALL, CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ALL,
    0, &dwEncoding, &dwContentType, &dwFormatType, &hStore, &hMsg, NULL);
```

- [**`Using CString`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/using-cstring?view=vs-2019).
- [**`CStringT Class`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=vs-2019) (some tech details).
- [The Complete Guide to C++ Strings - Part I](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2995/The-Complete-Guide-to-C-Strings-Part-I-Win-Chara) (chart, somewhat below mid-page).
- [The Complete Guide to C++ Strings - Part II](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3004/The-Complete-Guide-to-C-Strings-Part-II-String-Wra)

---

***Links***:

- From [github.com](https://www.github.com): [CryptQueryObjectSample.cpp](https://github.com/wangzhan/CryptQueryObjectSample/blob/master/CryptQueryObjectSample/CryptQueryObjectSample.cpp)

Comment: `CString` solves the issue, by coincidence, given your project settings. It doesn't do anything magical, and this answer is devoid of any explanation.

Comment: I am surprised you think this user doesn't know what Unicode is :-). That was basically implied, but anyway. I figured being able to step through the code would help and he would discover new problems, so I went with a simple tweak to get going again. The links I provided has technical string details - and the github links has a whole Crypt real-world sample?

Comment: I don't know who you are referring to with *"this user"*. It doesn't look like the OP is aware of what Unicode encoding to use in Windows (they are passing either UTF-8, ASCII, or ANSI). The code you presented doesn't use explicit Unicode versions of `CString`, nor does it use Unicode string literals. If it uses Unicode anywhere, it uses Unicode by accident rather than judiciously.